# How to solve could not load assembly using Sitecore7 and Glassmapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, glass-mapper

For a project I'm using [Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/) version 7 and the latest version of [GlassMapper](http://glass.lu/). It's an ASP.net MVC3  project. When I try to add a new controller, an error occured:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Can GlassMapper work with Sitecore version 7.0? Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I don't like it if I need to downgrade to Sitecore version 6.6.

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: It works with Sitecore 7, how did you install, using NuGet?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I used NuGet for installing GlassMapper.

Comment: Did you install version2 (Glass.Sitecore.Mapper) or version 3 (Glass.Mapper.Sc)?

Comment: Glass.Mapper.Sc Version 3.1.2.18.

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question, I think this is a Sitecore Rocks error. Make sure you are using the latest version

Comment: Why do you think that? I did not have any Sitecore Rocks connection. I use the latest version of Sitecore Rocks.

Comment: Looks like one of the dependencies is referring to Sitecore 6 in your solution?

Comment: Jordy were you able to get resolution to your problem? I am having the same problem expect my errors message indicates Glass.Mapper v3.1.7.26. So far this is the only mention of this type of problem that I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that one of the other assemblies is referencing sitecore 6 dll. You could override it in your configuration to use sitecore 7 like this.

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Sitecore.Kernel" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0-6.6.0.0" newVersion="7.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling sitecore?